# Mysql IN Subquery with additional value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select rows using IN but I want to add inside IN statement another value.

Example

```
SELECT title FROM film WHERE film_id IN (SELECT film_id FROM film_actor)
```

Ok... Get result..no problem..

```
SELECT title FROM film WHERE film_id IN ((SELECT film_id FROM film_actor), 130)
```

How can add another value (130) like the query above?

Tks.
Adriano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `union all`as below

```
SELECT title FROM film WHERE film_id IN (SELECT film_id FROM film_actor
                                         union all
                                         SELECT 130)
```

Comment: This is correct, just want to note that it doesn't matter that there's a union all, just union would work fine since the right-hand side operand of in is mostly considered as set.

Comment: @vonPetrushev Yes, but `union` is slower than `union all` because `union all` doesn't sort and remove duplicates.

Comment: @vonPetrushev `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` since `UNION` filters out unique values so there is an additional work in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

how about using `OR`?

```
WHERE film_id IN (SELECT film_id FROM film_actor) OR
      film_id = 130
```

if you have multiple values to be included,

```
WHERE film_id IN (SELECT film_id FROM film_actor) OR
      film_id IN (120, 130, 140, .....)
```